# Mass assignment error when seeding in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the faker class to help seeder my database. The DatabaseSeeder looks like this

```
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $tables = [
        'users',
        'posts',
    ];

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        DB::table($table)->truncate();
    }

    $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
    $this->call('PostsTableSeeder');
   }
}
```

and the UsersTableSeeder

```
<?php

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for( $i=0 ; $i<50 ; $i++ ) {
        $user = User::create([
            'first_name'         => $faker->firstName,
            'surname'            => $faker->lastName,
            'email'              => $faker->email,
            'username'           => $faker->userName,
            'bio'                => $faker->sentences,
            'bio_html'           => $faker->sentences,
            'wesbite'            => $faker->url,
            'twitter'            => $faker->word,
        ]);
    }   
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error in the terminal when I try and seed this table.

```
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException]  
first_name
```

If I try and seed both I get this

```
 [ErrorException]                                                                       
 preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

I thought including `Eloquent::unguard();` stopped this error? I am running the latest version of Laravel.

Answer (score 11):

`faker->sentences()` and `faker->paragraphs()` return **arrays** and your class expects to receive a string.

You can either use  `faker->text()`  or you can you can use

```
implode(" ",$faker->sentences());
```

Comment: Came here dumbfounded and this was my solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, i think you just need to do simple in your **DatabaseSeeder.php**, like this:

```
public function run()
{
  Eloquent::unguard();

  $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
  $this->call('PostsTableSeeder');
}
```

Your **UsersTableSeeder.php**, like these:

```
<?php

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    $faker = Faker::create();

    for( $i=0 ; $i<50 ; $i++ ) {
      $user = User::create([
        'first_name'         => $faker->firstName, // try using str_random(10)
        'surname'            => $faker->lastName,  // try using str_random(20)
        'email'              => $faker->email,
        'username'           => $faker->userName,  // $faker->unique()->userName
        'bio'                => $faker->sentences,
        'bio_html'           => $faker->sentences,
        'wesbite'            => $faker->url,
        'twitter'            => $faker->word,
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

And, in your model, **User.php**, add:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

I executed here and both worked:

```
php artisan db:seed
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

I configured laravel and faker, on composer, like these:

```
"require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
  "fzaninotto/faker": "dev-master"
},
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can define empty array of guarded fields in your model;

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = []; 
}
```

Comment: Why would this solution help if the `DatabaseSeeder` class calls `Eloquent::unguarded()`?

Comment: It helped me. I was getting the same error using a single seeder.